# Change NavigationSplitView to NavigationStack

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

In the Food Truck app [Apple Food Truck App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/food_truck_building_a_swiftui_multiplatform_app) the contentView has a NavigationSplitView to target iPadOS.

```
        NavigationSplitView {
            Sidebar(selection: $selection)
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                DetailColumn(selection: $selection, model: model)
            }
        }
...
```

I would like to change this to remove the navigationSplitView so that it targets iOS only. Something like this:

```
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Sidebar(selection: $selection)
                .navigationDestination(for: Panel.self) { panel in
                    DetailColumn(selection: $selection, model: model)
            }
        }


...
```

There are a couple of problems with this - the first problem is no navigation occurs.  This is fixed by removing the $selection in Sidecar().  The second problem is that when the app does navigate, it only navigates to ".truck". To fix this, I have to go into DetailColumn and change selection to @State and change the above code to:

```
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Sidebar(selection: $selection)
                .navigationDestination(for: Panel.self) { panel in
                    DetailColumn(selection: panel, model: model)
            }
        }
...
```

Even though this works, Xcode does complain that "A navigationDestination for “Food_Truck.Panel” was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used."

I think I am missing some understanding of how this should be approached, or the design of the app was done so that it works with NavigationSplitView and not NavigationStackView directly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow the changes you made, but I've made similar changes and the app works.

First, remove the selection in `Sidebar`. `Sidebar` should no longer have a `selection` property. You should just use the parameterless `List` initialiser.

```
struct Sidebar: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(value: Panel.truck) {
                Label("Truck", systemImage: "box.truck")
            }
            
            NavigationLink(value: Panel.orders) {
                Label("Orders", systemImage: "shippingbox")
            }
            ...
```

Then you can even get rid of the `selection` state in `ContentView`.

Next, `selection` in `DetailColumn` need not be a `Binding` anymore. It is merely used to determine which detail view to show, and `DetailColumn` doesn't change it at all, so it can be a `let`.

```
struct DetailColumn: View {
    let selection: Panel?
    @ObservedObject var model: FoodTruckModel
    @State var timeframe: Timeframe = .today
    var body: some View {
        switch selection ?? .truck {
        case .truck:
            TruckView(model: model) // TruckView no longer needs to take the selection
         ...
```

Note that `TruckView` doesn't need to take a `$selection` binding. `TruckView` only uses it in the `cardNavigation` computed property. This property just decides how navigation should be done. Notice that on iPhones, this always returns `.navigationLink`. So you can just change it to:

```
var cardNavigation: TruckCardHeaderNavigation {
    .navigationLink
}
```

and remove `@Binding var navigationSelection: Panel?`.

Finally, the code in `ContentView` looks like this:

```
NavigationStack(path: $path) {
    Sidebar()
        .navigationDestination(for: Panel.self) { panel in
            DetailColumn(selection: panel, model: model)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sweeper, that does work, but I am still getting a debug message "A navigationDestination for “Food_Truck.Panel” was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used."

Comment: @mickeysox What did you to get that? I do not get that by just randomly navigating to different views. What did you specifically do? I would suggest making a [mcve] - remove as much code as you can from the sample code, and leave only the code that reproduces the issue. Then edit your question with that code, so that people don’t have to download the sample code in order to reproduce the issue. In the process of doing this, you might even find out what is causing this on your own :)

Comment: Thanks Sweeper - the issue is caused by the fact that there are 2 .navigationDestination, one in ContentView and one in TruckView - hence message states swift will take the "closest to the root view" which in this case would be the one in ContentView.  Just wondering why you don't actually get this message - should be the very first message in the debug window.  I get this by selecting Truck in the list view.

Comment: @mickeysox I just realised I had only the "left panel" (where it shows you all the variable values) of the debugger open, and had the "right panel" (where the console is) collapsed. Silly me! Now I see the message. I didn't notice `TruckView` had a `navigationDestination` modifier too. The one in `TruckView` can be safely removed, I think. The switch just covers a subset of the views that the switch in `DetailColumn` covers.